# TopLinks getting stripped in Magento

Tags: magento

I am using a modified version of `blank_seo` theme for Magento with the `ES_ES` language pack.

It seems as if the `topLinks` block is stripping the text, thus leaving out meaningful information. In this case the number of articles in my chart:

notice the `(rtículos)` that should have something like `(4 artículos)`

[image]

This comes from the `frontend/default/blank_seo/template/page/template/links.phtml` template file.

[image]

Which is:

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
<ul class="links"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
    <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So my first deduction is that `$_link->getLabel()` is stripping down the text (and so is `$_link->getTitle()` then).

So the first question is **how to disable the stripping of strings in `getLabel()`**?

But maybe this is not happening and another completely other thing could be happening which then escapes my understanding (something to do with the language pack perhaps?)

In this case, I'd like to know if anyone ran into this in the Spanish language pack and how can this be fixed?

Thankyou

Comment: do you have firebug installed? if no check the page source. It might be that there are 4 articulos, but simply not enough width for it to display

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov the stripping is not overflow-related, the source shows the same string.

Comment: in the translation csv file (app/locale/es_ES/Mage_Checkout.csv), look for the strings starting with "My Cart (%s item" and check the spanish translation (aka what comes after the coma, or in the second column)

Comment: @OSdave this is what the csv file has: `"My Cart (%s items)","Mi carrito (% artículos)"`. So far all correct :s

Comment: @OSdave It turns out the **%s** was missing! Please post as an answer (with what I just explained) and I will be happy to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the translation csv file (**app/locale/es_ES/Mage_Checkout.csv**), check that the translation string is correct, it should be: `"My Cart (%s items)","Mi carrito (%s artículos)"`.
I have checked that it is correct in the [language package](http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/7/es_ES), where did you get your translation? (I'm just asking to notify the author)

Comment: I used the [Magento Community Modules - Spanish (Spain) Language Pack](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-spanish-spain-language-pack.html), which is really bad. I will try the one you point out. Thank you!